# Detect the finish of `UIPopoverController` programmatic dismissal animation

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

[`UIPopoverControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html) protocol have `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` method which invoked after popover has finished it's dismissal animation. However, if popover is dismissed programmatically, above-mentioned delegate method is not called.

Is there any way to detect the finish of programmatically triggered dismissal animation? In a nutshell, how to implement something like `-[UIPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:completion:]`?

P.S. Running completion block with 0.5 seconds timer is ugly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, if popover is dismissed programmatically, above-mentioned delegate method is not called.

A popover in iOS 8 is a presented view controller. Thus, if a popover is dismissed programmatically nowadays, it is done by calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` which has a completion block where you'll be called back. You should not be using UIPopoverController at all.